# Assigning properties to an object

Tags: c#, object, reflection, properties

Okay so I have a small section of code which creates a list of objects based on the data model.  I don't want to have to create a class for this.  It is used on n ASP.net MVC application for populating a user notifications list.

I know there are plenty of other ways to do this such as actually setting up a class for it(probably the easiest method), but I would like to know if there is a way to do what is displayed below.

```
        List<object> notificationList = new List<object>();

        object userNotification = new { Text = "Here is some text!", Url = "http://www.google.com/#q=notifications" };
        notificationList.Add(userNotification);


        foreach(object notification in notificationList)
        {
            string value = notification.Text;
        }
```

So I haven't populated the list much but for the purposes here you get the idea.  After debug I notice that the Text and Url properties exist, however cannot code to get the values???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `dynamic` as variable type in the foreach:

```
foreach(dynamic notification in notificationList)
{
    string value = notification.Text;
}
```

Comment: Awesome stuff Alberto, worked like a charm.  I was looking into it further when I saw mention of the var method which did not work in this case because of the foreach loop I assume. dynamic was the way to go. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**  Oops ... you do need "dynamic", either as the List's generic type, or in the foreach.

```
      var notificationList = new List<dynamic>();

      var userNotification = new { Text = "Here is some text!", Url = "http://www.google.com/#q=notifications" };
      notificationList.Add(userNotification);


      foreach (var notification in notificationList)
      {
        string value = notification.Text;
      }
```

**End edit**

Anonymous types should be declared using the [`var`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) keyword:

```
var userNotification = new { Text = "Here is some text!", Url = "http://www.google.com/#q=notifications" };
```

---

You could also use "dynamic" instead of "var", but that deprives you of compile-time checks, and it appears unnecessary in this case (because the type is fully defined at compile time, within the same method scope).  A case where you *would* need to use "dynamic" is where you want to pass the anonymous-typed object as a parameter to another function, eg:

```
void Func1()
{
    var userNotification = new { Text = "Here is some text!", Url = "http://www.google.com/#q=notifications" };
    Func2(userNotification);
}

void Func2(dynamic userNotification)
{
    string value = notification.Text;
}
```

Comment: that is not going to work if you do not specify `dynamic` in the foreach.

Answer (score 0):

Well you *could* declare the list as an list of `dynimac` objects:

```
    List<dynamic> notificationList = new List<object>();

    var userNotification = new { Text = "Here is some text!", Url = "http://www.google.com/#q=notifications" };
    notificationList.Add(userNotification);

    foreach(dynamic notification in notificationList)
    {
        string value = notification.Text;
    }
```

or use `var` to let the compiler choose the type:

```
    var notificationList = new [] 
              {
                   new { Text = "Here is some text!", Url = "http://www.google.com/#q=notifications" }
              }.ToList();

    foreach(var notification in notificationList)
    {
        string value = notification.Text;
    }
```